# Van Der Pol ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I'm having troubles linearising and solving for the Van Der Pol equation

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - (1-x^2)\frac{dx}{dt}+x =0$

with initial cond $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=1$

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Our initial conditions are different, that case has (0,0) whereas this is not zero, it's 1